# drupal_add_js is removing jQuery

Tags: 7, javascript

I have the following in my module.

```
drupal_add_js(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'responsive_videos') . '/js/fluidvids.js',
    array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'scope' => 'footer',
        'weight' => 10,
    )
);
```

For some reason, when this module is enabled, jQuery and jQuery Once get removed from the head and the JavaScript console logs many "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". Can anyone clarify why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Here is the info file, responsive_videos.info.

```
name = Responsive Video
description = Creates a fluid responsive video from YouTube or Vimeo embedded iframes.
core = 7.x
```

And here is the module file, responsive_video.module.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Makes YouTube and Vimeo embedded iframe videos responsive.
 */

drupal_add_js(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'responsive_video') . '/js/fluidvids.js',
    array('scope' => 'footer')
);
```

The JavaScript file being added does not leverage jQuery, so I don't quite understand how or if it might interfere with jQuery being added to the page, but here is the source of the "fluidvids.js" file.

```
// http://toddmotto.com/fluid-and-responsive-youtube-and-vimeo-videos-with-fluidvids-js/
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory;
  } else {
    root.fluidvids = factory();
  }
})(this, function () {

  'use strict';

  var fluidvids = {
    selector: ['iframe'],
    players: ['www.youtube.com', 'player.vimeo.com']
  };

  var css = [
    '.fluidvids {',
      'width: 100%; max-width: 100%; position: relative;',
    '}',
    '.fluidvids-item {',
      'position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;',
    '}'
  ].join('');

  var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

  function matches (src) {
    return new RegExp('^(https?:)?\/\/(?:' + fluidvids.players.join('|') + ').*$',     'i').test(src);
  }

  function getRatio (height, width) {
    return ((parseInt(height, 10) / parseInt(width, 10)) * 100) + '%';
  }

  function fluid (elem) {
    if (!matches(elem.src) || !!elem.getAttribute('data-fluidvids')) return;
    var wrap = document.createElement('div');
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, elem);
    elem.className += (elem.className ? ' ' : '') + 'fluidvids-item';
    elem.setAttribute('data-fluidvids', 'loaded');
    wrap.className += 'fluidvids';
    wrap.style.paddingTop = getRatio(elem.height, elem.width);
    wrap.appendChild(elem);
  }

  function addStyles () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<p>x</p><style>' + css + '</style>';
    head.appendChild(div.childNodes[1]);
  }

  fluidvids.render = function () {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(fluidvids.selector.join());
    var i = nodes.length;
    while (i--) {
      fluid(nodes[i]);
    }
  };

  fluidvids.init = function (obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
      fluidvids[key] = obj[key];
    }
    fluidvids.render();
    addStyles();
  };

  return fluidvids;

});

fluidvids.init();
```

Comment: Can you show your JS?

Comment: @Andy, Just added the source of the JavaScript file to the question description. Please let me know if anything seems like it would interfere with jQuery being added to the head of the document.

Comment: What files are the error messages occurring in? The console tells you that as well. What other Javascript files get loaded on the page where you get the errors?

Comment: Thanks. Can I just confirm that you've checked the markup, and the jquery script tag appears/disappears as you disable/enable the module?

Comment: @Andy, I have confirmed that jQuery is missing from the markup when the module is enabled. jQuery is present in the markup when the module is disabled.

Comment: I don't think the JS or the `drupal_add_js()` are the culprits then. (You can test this by commenting out the `drupal_add_js()` and seeing if jQuery starts working.) What else does the module do?

Comment: @Andy, it is a very minimal module, all it does is add the fluidvids script to the footer of the document. I suspect I should call drupal_add_js from a hook, but haven't found the right one to use yet, or a good example of the right one to use.

Comment: @Andy, I updated the question with the source of the info and module files.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the code was already in a hook. On which pages do you want it? You can [add it to every page page with the info file](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#adding-javascript).

Comment: @Andy, that was a fair assumption. I was not aware of a way to add JavaScript with the info file to the footer, so I began working with an implementation of drupal_add_js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16466/discussion-between-jerome-and-andy).

Comment: Per suggestion from @Andy, I have updated the module to use the info file to add the script. I would still like to know how to effectively add JavaScript to the footer on a case by case basis, however.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it was breaking is because you’re doing `drupal_add_js` outside of any function or listener hook.

You need to add it to the appropriate build, alter or preprocess hook that suits your needs.

Comment: This should be the best answer. Rookie mistake that I recently made and this was the reason for it. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I solved it using page_build hook.

Example:

-module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build(&$page).
 */
function product_admin_link_control_page_build(&$page) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'product_admin_link_control') . '/product_admin_link_control_init.js', 
    array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer'));
}
```

-product_admin_link_control_init.js file:

```
(function ($) {
try{
  console.info("in");
}catch(oe){}
})(jQuery);
```

-info file:

```
; $Id: $
name = Product admin link control
description = Features: removes admin link from CK2 product title for non admins.
package = Commerce (contrib)
core = 7.x

; Base module files


datestamp = "1437076940"
```